# pylint and pre-commit hook unable to import

Tags: pylint, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

My project structure looks like this:

```
project/
   app/
      main.py
   venv/
   .pylintrc
   .pre-commit-config.yaml
```

When I am trying to edit `project/app/main.py` and it fails with

```
Unable to import 'psycopg2' (import-error)
```

But when I am trying to pylint this file directly, it works.

`.pre-commit-config.yaml` looks like this:

```
-   repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint
    rev: pylint-2.4.2
    hooks:
    -   id: pylint
```

Answer (score 32):

not sure if this made it into pylint proper but there's a disclaimer on the bottom of [pre-commit/mirrors-pylint](https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-pylint)

> pre-commit runs pylint from an isolated virtualenv. Many of pylint's checks perform dynamic analysis which will fail there. You may find configuring pylint as a [`local` hook](https://pre-commit.com/#repository-local-hooks) more useful.

if you have very few dependencies, `additional_dependencies` might be enough to make it work, but using `local` hooks for things which need to (~essentially) import your code is probably your best bet

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of `pre-commit`

Comment: The issue applies at least to flake8, pylint and mypy. If one takes these out of the pre-commit set of hooks they will likely ask themselves why to use pre-commit at all.  I do not imply they should, just that current design limits its practical use considerably.

Comment: flake8 does not need your installed dependencies -- and it's fairly easy to get mypy working by explicitly listing your typed dependencies.  I don't use pylint personally so I don't have any experience there

Answer (score 2):

You can disable import error in pylint args. This should not conflict with other types:

```yaml
- repo: https://github.com/pycqa/pylint
  rev: v2.17.5
  hooks:
    - id: pylint
      args: [src, --disable=import-error]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found (at least for me) a quite better solution.

I just looked at the official documentation: https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/installation/pre-commit-integration.html

My `.pre-commit-config.yaml` looks like the following:

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint
    rev: v3.0.3
    hooks:
    -   id: pylint
        language: system
```

If I understand this correctly the `language: system` defines that `pylint` will be executed from the `system`. Normally `pre-commit` creates an own environment to execute the hooks. In this environment your dependencies aren't installed, so you get an `Unable to load import`. You only must make sure you install `pylint` on your own into your environment along your dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

One workaround that I used in the past was to force pre-commit to install current project. Be warned that while this works is not supported by the author of pre-commit in any way, in fact being actively discouraged, mainly because it prevents pre-commit from using immutable caches.

Once the virtualenv is created it will not be updated again and pre-commit does not have any command line option to tell to not trust local cache. If you get into errors your only option is to reset the entire pre-commit disk cache, this likely means removing gigabytes of data from `~/.cache./pre-commit` when you run `pre-commit clean`. Doing that will slowdown running pre-commit on all other projects you have... :(

Ideally the tool should have an option to invalidate only the environments from the current project and not entire cache.

```yaml
- repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-pylint
  rev: v3.0.0a3
  hooks:
  - id: pylint
    additional_dependencies:
    - .  # <-- that makes it install current project
    - flaky
```

Comment: this does not work, `.` will install `mirrors-pylint` and not your project